# C# P/Invoke void** pointer pass

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, void-pointers

I'm using WINAPI dll written in C++ using DllImport for accessing USB ADC/DAC converter values.
The only problem is:

```
long ZGetBufferADC(long typeDevice, long numberDSP, void **buffer, long *size)
```

I've translated it into

```
[DllImport("Zadc.dll")]
public static extern Int32 ZGetBufferADC(Int32 typeDevice, Int32 numberDSP, out IntPtr    buffer, out Int32 size);
```

I call this function like that

```
Int32 err = ZGetBufferADC(typeDevice, numberDSP, out pBuffer, out sizeBufferADC);
```

Then I need to access resulting pBuffer in C# like that in C++:

```
short *pBuffer16ADC = (short*) pBuffer
volt0 = resolutionADC0 * (pBuffer16ADC[pointerADC]) / amplifyADC0;
```

where pointerADC is Int32 pointing to current value of ADC converter, i managed to get it w/o problems correctly

so how could i implement that structure in c#? I tried defining variables like that

```
IntPtr pBuffer;
Int16 pBuffer16ADC; 
pBuffer16ADC = (Int16)pBuffer;
volt0 = resolutionADC0 * (pBuffer16ADC[pointerADC]) / amplifyADC0;
```

but that throws an error

```
Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'short'
```

Any help will be appreciated! If additional info is needed please ask i'll provide ASAP.
This issue is driving me nuts for almost a week :(
Thanks!

Comment: Having `IntPtr buffer` filled by `ZGetBufferADC`, use `IntPtr p = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(buffer);` Then `pBuffer16ADC = Marshal.ReadInt16(p);`

Comment: Assuming that C++ code is `short *pBuffer16ADC = (short*) *pBuffer;` Your C++ code fragment doesn't match function definition.

Comment: That's something! If I apply your code then same error about indexing appears. However, when I omitted the index program compiled well but on Marshall.ReadInt16(p) throws System.AccessViolationException was unhandled (cannot write memory) . Locals show that p variable is negative number (-2359241).

Comment: For the second comment: `code short *pBuffer16ADC = (short*)` pBuffer (w/o asterisk before pBuffer) that it's how it's written in c++ assuming pBuffer is defined like void *pBuffer; Can I upload code somewhere? It's not large, and easy-to-read. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: I don't know how @Alex reached that conclusion. You presumably pass `&pBuffer16ADC` to the function. And that is a double pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably `size` is measured in bytes. If instead, `size` is the number of elements, it should be obvious how to adapt the following.

First of all, call the function as you are doing:

```
Int32 err = ZGetBufferADC(typeDevice, numberDSP, out pBuffer, out sizeBufferADC);
```

Then declare an array into which you copy the buffer.

```
short[] buffer = new short[sizeBufferADC/Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(short))];
```

Finally copy the buffer:

```
Marshal.Copy(pBuffer, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

And that should be all you need to do.

Comment: Can't thank you enough, it's working flawlessly :) However, it worth noting that in C# it's `short[] buffer`, this could confuse someone somehow) But the idea is awesome, so simple and stable.

Comment: Thanks. Glad it helped. Too much C++ lately, hence the syntax slip. Now fixed. Perhaps I should have used var!!

Comment: There is a problem with `Marshal.Copy`....it's awful perfomance-wise, because my buffer is constantly changing and copying it in every timer tick is costly. I thought if I could get away with `Marshal.ReadIntPtr` instead, but i can't figure out what offset is needed. I tried `Marshal.ReadIntPtr(pBuffer,pointerADC*sizeof(short))`, pBuffer is IntPtr, pointerADC is the index of 16-bit array, like that: `pBuffer16ADC[pointerADC]` where `short[] pBuffer16ADC = new short[sizeBufferADC];` size in 16-bit words.

Comment: There's not a whole lot you can do about that given the interface of the function. I'd expect that a C++/CLI mixed mode wrapper would perform better.